# Is it possible to check which all profile have access to a apex class salesforce

Tags: apex, permissions, profile

I have have created a new apex class. The old apex class have access to certain profiles new i need to give the same access to newly created apex class. Do anyone have any idea how to get the list of access profile to my old apex class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the old apex class exists in a sandbox or even still in production, you can go into that [apex class view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_apex_access_via_list.htm&type=5) and use the `Security` button to see a list of profiles with access.

`Setup --> Apex Classes --> find your apex class and click on it`

It should look like so

[image]

Clicking on it brings up two select boxes and the one on the right shows the `Enabled Profiles` that have access to it. Simply make the same selections on your new apex class to match the old.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The same result described by @Kris Goncalves can be achieved declaratively using a simple SOQL query:

```
SELECT Name, (
        SELECT Parent.Profile.Name
        FROM SetupEntityAccessItems
)
FROM ApexClass
WHERE Name = 'ApexClassName'
```

> [SetupEntityAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupentityaccess.htm) represents the enabled setup entity access settings (such as for Apex classes) for the parent PermissionSet.

**NOTE**
As of Spring ’20 and later, only users with "View Setup and Configuration" permission can access this object.